# How to run tail and grep in a crontab

Tags: unix, logging, cron, grep, tail

I am trying to run a tail and grep command that gets the last 10 lines containing Error in all logfiles in the folderevery minute using crontab and fill a text file with the output. The line below is the only line I have in my crontab. If i run the command in a normal terminal it shows me the results so the command works, but not in the crontab.
Is there anything I am missing?

`* * * * * cd /Users/nassim/Desktop/application1 && tail -n 10 | grep -w "Error" **/*.log >  error.txt`

Comment: Your tail command is incomplete, you must specify the file name.  The command, as written here has no chance of working, even in a normal terminal.

Comment: It does work in a normal terminal.    "** / *.log" selects all .log files in the folder and subfolders.

Comment: `tail -n 10` by itself does nothing but wait for text from stdin. If I do `tail -n 10 | grep something *`, I do get the results of the grep, but the terminal waits there until I do a ctrl-c, or feed it some text.  Remove `&& tail -n 10` and your crontab will work ok. What are you trying to do with that tail? Check only the last 10 files from the directory?

Comment: tail -n 10 is used to print the last 10 lines of a log or text file. In this case it gets the last 10 lines of the log files en checks those lines for the word 'Error'. I use this to get better performance.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-command-linux-examples/

Comment: yes but tail needs a file argument.  Here you do `cd DIRECTORY && tail -n 10`, it should be `cd DIRECTORY && tail -n 10 SOMEFILE`.  SOMEFILE can be a specific file, or a wildcard specifying some files (ex. `*`).  `tail -n 10` alone waits for some input from stdin (which could be something you type).

Comment: If you want the last 10 lines from your grep, do `cd DIRECTORY && grep -v "Error" *.log | tail -n 10`.  This way the output of grep is passed to tail (so tail takes its input from stdin, which is piped from the stdout of grep).